# Oil checked when car was on

Tags: oil, dipstick

Car is a 2020 Hyundai i10

Sorry for what I know is probably a completely dumb question, but I’d like to put my mind to rest and I am no where near mechanically minded.

A friend told me to double check my oil level in my new car as they had one delivered with barely any oil in it or it used too much up quickly.

When I checked, I had no idea that you had to turn the car off (completely stupid, I know now)

When I done this and took the stick out 2 times for all of 10 seconds each time, I noticed my exhaust note got louder as if it made my revs go up. As soon as I put it back in, it went away.

My main concern is, did I cause any damage and/or changes to my car.

Thank you so much!

P.S. i am obviously now aware that it was an innaccurate reading and will do it correctly next time.

Comment: As you've learned in the answer below, no damage was done. The RPM change is due to a new source of atmospheric pressure confusing the vehicle computer, for the brief time the stick was out.

Answer (score 2):

This caused absolutely no damage to your car. Yes, check your oil with the engine off and on level ground. Really, if you don't know, this isn't a stupid question ... you just don't know. Enjoy your new car.

Comment: Paul is correct. No damage done. You may have noticed that your oil dipstick has an o-ring seal on it. This is because the engine crankcase is sealed (and under a slight vacuum) to prevent vapor emissions. By pulling up on the dipstick you introduced a slight vacuum leak to the system, hence the change to engine speed. One time occurrence, no worries. Driving all day without a dipstick in the tube, that wouldn’t be good.

Comment: As long as I didn’t create any damage, or a permanent vaccum leak or extra stress on the long term. 

Thank you too @zipzit I’m usually really careful with not touching stuff I know nothing about. I’m assuming when I put it back in that small vaccum leak I introduced is simply sealed again and no more?

Comment: @NovicePerson873 - That's exactly right.